# SEO questions about website page titles

Tags: seo, google, title, heading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should my Title tag be the same as my H1 tag?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/should-my-title-tag-be-the-same-as-my-h1-tag)

- should the `<title>` tag be the same as the `<h1>` tag?
- should the `<title>` tag contain the website name too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard recommendation is **Yes to the first question** and **No to the second** but there are no absolutes.

Both the title and H1 should at least use the same keywords but you may vary it to suit how the H1 is displayed. The H1 is almost always more visible to the user, so search engines tend to emphasize it more.

For the business name, if you want to include it, it is recommended to place it at the end in case it gets truncated when displayed on a tab. Plus, words at the beginning are given more importance for SEO. So you may guess that if a page is *about* the business and the business has its own distinct brand, there are cases where putting it first makes sense.